# fprintf an integer array

Tags: arrays, c, printf

So I want to print an integer array to my document. To do it so I tried these:

Changing my integer array to char array:

```
char* intAtocharA(int* k,int n){
    char *z = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        z[i]=(char)k[i];
    }
    return z;
}
```

does not give me an error but won't do what I want.

For additional info in my int main I did these:

```
FILE* fout = fopen(argv[1],"w");  
char* l =intAtocharA(arr,arrsize);   
fprintf(fout,l);
```

I don't know if it is relevant but my integer array is full of 1's and 0's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l` is an array of (small) integers, not a null-terminated string which is what the `printf` format string is supposed to be.

You need to use a loop and print all numbers one by one:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i)
{
    fprintf(fout, "%hhd ", l[i]);
}
```